# Angular and OneDrive: unsyncable directory "~" in node_modules\postcss-initial

Tags: angular, onedrive

I'm using angular and the project files are on a local-synced OneDrive directory

OneDrive throws an error, that a directory with name "~" can't be synced

Does anyone else have the same problen?

[image]

Comment: Why do you have your project files in a OneDrive directory? Use proper source control.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's possible OP is using source control in addition to OneDrive. There might be some files that aren't suitable to be committed into a VCS, but which they nevertheless want cloud backups of.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive doesn't support syncing a folder called "~".

If you let OneDrive rename it to "_" then the only thing you lose is the functionality of the postcss-initial module ...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-initial

If you can live without that functionality, then just let OD rename it.

I raised a suggestion to have the folder name changed ...

https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-initial/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive will automatically change such folder names.
Click on oneDrive logo from hidden icons in task bar. Allow onedrive to change the name of folder.